# VBA Powerpoint Grouping Array?

Tags: vba, grouping, powerpoint, shapes, powerpoint-2007

I want to create a code that will resize a selected image, position it accordingly, create 2 text boxes beneath it, and finally group the image and 2 text boxes together.

My overall goal is to make 2 additional macros that will do the same function but position them in the middle and right.

I can't seem to figure out how to group the 3 shapes.

Here's my code below.

```
Dim LeftPic As ShapeRange, sld As Slide, ByeBox As Shape, HelloBox As Shape

Set LeftPic = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

With LeftPic
    .Left = 0.17 * 72 '72 is the multiplier for the inch
    .Top = 1.83 * 72
    .Height = 4.27 * 72
    .Width = 3.2 * 72
End With

LeftPic.Name = "LeftPic"

Set HelloBox = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    0.17 * 72, Top:=6.17 * 72, Width:=200, Height:=50)
HelloBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello"
HelloBox.Name = "HelloBox"

Set ByeBox = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
0.17 * 72, Top:=6.42 * 72, Width:=200, Height:=50)
ByeBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Goodbye"
ByeBox.Name = "ByeBox"

Shapes.Range(Array("HelloBox", "ByeBox", "LeftPic")).Group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim LeftPic As ShapeRange, sld As Slide, ByeBox As Shape, HelloBox As Shape

Set LeftPic = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

With LeftPic
    .Left = 0.17 * 72 '72 is the multiplier for the inch
    .Top = 1.83 * 72
    .Height = 4.27 * 72
    .Width = 3.2 * 72
End With

LeftPic.Name = "LeftPic"

Set HelloBox = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    0.17 * 72, Top:=6.17 * 72, Width:=200, Height:=50)
HelloBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello"
HelloBox.Name = "HelloBox"

Set ByeBox = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
0.17 * 72, Top:=6.42 * 72, Width:=200, Height:=50)
ByeBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Goodbye"
ByeBox.Name = "ByeBox"

sld.Shapes("HelloBox").Select
sld.Shapes("ByeBox").Select msoFalse
sld.Shapes("LeftPic").Select msoFalse
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group
```

Answer (score 4):

I like ZebraOnWheels' approach for this problem, but more generally, you just need a bit of help with the syntax for Array (it's a bit improbable).  Example:

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim TempArray() As Variant
Dim oGroup As Shape

Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

With oSl
  TempArray = Array(.Shapes("Bob").Name, _
                    .Shapes("Carol").Name, _
                    .Shapes("Ted").Name, _
                    .Shapes("Alice").Name)
  Set oGroup = .Shapes.Range(TempArray).Group
End With
```

See what's going on there?  You have to pass Array the .Name property of references to shapes, not just the shape names.

Comment: My pleasure.  To tell the truth, I took notes the third time I worked this out (after forgetting it all the first couple of times) and had to look up my notes this time.  ;-)